# typeof of an object property (number) on passing to IIFE is returning undefined. Why?

Tags: javascript, html, iife

How in the world the output is not number?

- There is a simple function (IIFE) which is being passed an object, property of which is a number
- When we are trying to find typeof of that property which refers to a number, the result is 'undefined'

How?

```html
<script>

x = (function(foo){
  return typeof(foo.bar);
})({ foo: { bar: 1 } });

console.log(x);

</script>
```

Comment: You mixed up the names. `foo` is the object name, but the object has a *property* named `foo` too (which is a nested object which contains a property named `bar`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If should be `foo.foo.bar`

`foo` parameter is an object with a property called `foo` in it

```js
x = (function(foo) {
  return typeof(foo.foo.bar);
})({ foo: { bar: 1 } });

console.log(x);
```

You probably meant to destructure the argument like this:

```js
x = (function({ foo }) {
  return typeof(foo.bar);
})({ foo: { bar: 1 } });

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

foo is the  argument. You have to access the properties inside the function using . notation

```js
x = (function(foo){
  return typeof(foo.foo.bar);
})({ foo: { bar: 1 } });

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `foo` argument in your function is the entire object (not the nested one):

```
{ foo: { bar: 1 } }
```

So, when you do `foo.bar` there is no `bar` property, and so you get `undefined`.

Thus, `typeof undefined` will give you `"undefined"`. Instead, you can use clearer property names so the type of each object is easy to understand, and then access the `foo` property from your argument:

```js
x = (function(obj){
  return typeof(obj.foo.bar);
})({ foo: { bar: 1 } });

console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can destructure `foo` in the function argument.

```js
let x = (function({foo}){
  return typeof(foo.bar);
})({ foo: { bar: 1 } });

console.log(x);
```